# Unable to get the value in double quotes that is dynamically displayed using selenium xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get the value "19.5" which is dynamically displayed in below code using xpath in selenium. can anyone please help me with xpath to get the value 19.5, I'm new to selenium.

```html
<li>
  <label for="applyleave_leaveBalance">Leave Balance</label>
  <div id="applyleave_leaveBalance" class>
    "19.50"
    <a href="#balance_details" data-toggle="modal" id="leaveBalance_details_link">view details</a>
 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Which _Language Binding_? Java/Python/C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more of the *outerHTML* would have made the solution a bit easier. However as per the *HTML* you have provided to extract the value **19.5** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table[aria-label='User']")));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Leave Balance')]//following::div[@id='applyleave_leaveBalance']")));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I 'm able to extract the value now.

Answer (score 0):

please follow below steps
(1) take locator as

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='applyleave_leaveBalance']")
private WebElement balance;

public void printBalance()
{
System.out.println(balance.getText());
}
```

Comment: This will also extract the text of child link

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
xpath="//div[@id='applyleave_leaveBalance']/text()[1]"
```

It will return first text node.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.